# Calculations within subsets of dataframe [R]

Tags: r, plyr, subset, tapply

Facing difficulties with subset calculations. I am able to get overall stats like average purchase by customer (factor) using `ave`, `tapply`, `ddply` but I am not able to calculate **visit by visit** stats for each customer. Some simplified data below to illustrate my data and ideal results.

Current Dataframe:
(Note that visit #1 is the most recent visit)

```
  customer  visit      date    purchase_amt
    sarah          2    2013-08-09      5
    sarah          3    2013-07-21      8
    sarah          4    2013-06-23      9
    sarah          5    2013-06-02      1
    sarah          1    2013-08-20      8
    henry          1    2013-07-04      4
    che            1    2013-08-27      2
    che            2    2013-07-27      1
    che            3    2013-07-05      8
    che            4    2013-06-14      3
    dt             3    2013-04-05      9
    dt             2    2013-06-07      1
    dt             1    2013-07-11      6
```

These are the results I am seeking:

```
customer  visit    date purchase_amt    days since  amt_diff
sarah       2   2013-08-09  5               19        -3
sarah       3   2013-07-21  8               28        -1
sarah       4   2013-06-23  9               21         8
sarah       5   2013-06-02  1               NA        NA
sarah       1   2013-08-20  8               11         3
henry       1   2013-07-04  4               NA        NA
che         1   2013-08-27  2               31         1
che         2   2013-07-27  1               22        -7
che         3   2013-07-05  8               21         5
che         4   2013-06-14  3               NA        NA
dt          3   2013-04-05  9               NA        NA
dt          2   2013-06-07  1               63        -8
dt          1       2013-07-11    6         34         5
```

So in summary, I would like to find most recent visit of a customer and the attributes of it, then find the next visit attributes and calculate various stats on the two. Return "NA" when there are no more previous visits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution only uses the base of R and retains the original order of the input:

```
# Sort, calculate differences and unsort.
# r is row indexes to use, order.by is ordering vector, col is vector to difference

diffs <- function(r, order.by, col) {
    order.by <- order.by[r]
    col <- col[r]
    o <- order(order.by)
    replace(r, o, c(NA, diff(col[o])))
}

# fun specialized to arguments after first, i.e. subsequent arguments curried

curry <- function (fun, ...) function(r) fun(r, ...)

ix <- 1:nrow(DF)
transform(DF, 
    days_since = ave(ix, customer, FUN = curry(diffs, date, date)),
    amt_diff = ave(ix, customer, FUN = curry(diffs, date, purchase_amt))
)
```

The result is:

```
   customer visit       date purchase_amt days_since amt_diff
1     sarah     2 2013-08-09            5         19       -3
2     sarah     3 2013-07-21            8         28       -1
3     sarah     4 2013-06-23            9         21        8
4     sarah     5 2013-06-02            1         NA       NA
5     sarah     1 2013-08-20            8         11        3
6     henry     1 2013-07-04            4         NA       NA
7       che     1 2013-08-27            2         31        1
8       che     2 2013-07-27            1         22       -7
9       che     3 2013-07-05            8         21        5
10      che     4 2013-06-14            3         NA       NA
11       dt     3 2013-04-05            9         NA       NA
12       dt     2 2013-06-07            1         63       -8
13       dt     1 2013-07-11            6         34        5
```

UPDATE: minor improvements to code.

Comment: Thanks. This ultimately worked out the best for me and is flexible for future calculations other than difference.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this? Assuming your data is called `df`:

```
library(plyr)

# convert dates to class 'Date'
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)

# order by customer and date
df <- df[order(df$customer, df$date), ]
# or since plyr is loaded anyway:
df <- arrange(df, customer, date) 

# per customer, calculate differences in date and purchase, between consecutive visits
# pad differences with a leading NA
df2 <- ddply(.data = df, .variables = .(customer), mutate,
      days_since = c(NA, diff(date)),
      amt_diff = c(NA, diff(purchase_amt)))

df2
# customer visit       date purchase_amt days_since amt_diff
# 1       che     4 2013-06-14            3         NA       NA
# 2       che     3 2013-07-05            8         21        5
# 3       che     2 2013-07-27            1         22       -7
# 4       che     1 2013-08-27            2         31        1
# 5        dt     3 2013-04-05            9         NA       NA
# 6        dt     2 2013-06-07            1         63       -8
# 7        dt     1 2013-07-11            6         34        5
# 8     henry     1 2013-07-04            4         NA       NA
# 9     sarah     5 2013-06-02            1         NA       NA
# 10    sarah     4 2013-06-23            9         21        8
# 11    sarah     3 2013-07-21            8         28       -1
# 12    sarah     2 2013-08-09            5         19       -3
# 13    sarah     1 2013-08-20            8         11        3
```

Comment: This worked very well on my sample data but took up too much data for my larger dataframe. Very nice and simple solution!

Answer (score 5):

Here is the data.table solution in line with @Henrik:

```
    df<-structure(list(customer = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("che", "dt", "henry", 
"sarah"), class = "factor"), visit = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), date = structure(c(15926, 15907, 
15879, 15858, 15937, 15890, 15944, 15913, 15891, 15870, 15800, 
15863, 15897), class = "Date"), purchase_amt = c(5L, 8L, 9L, 
1L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 1L, 6L)), .Names = c("customer", 
"visit", "date", "purchase_amt"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class =  
"data.frame")

library(data.table)
 df<-data.table(df)
df[,list(visit=visit,date=date, purchase_amt=purchase_amt,days_since = c(NA, diff(date)),amt_diff = c(NA, diff(purchase_amt))),keyby="customer"]
    customer visit       date purchase_amt days_since amt_diff
 1:      che     1 2013-08-27            2         NA       NA
 2:      che     2 2013-07-27            1        -31       -1
 3:      che     3 2013-07-05            8        -22        7
 4:      che     4 2013-06-14            3        -21       -5
 5:       dt     3 2013-04-05            9         NA       NA
 6:       dt     2 2013-06-07            1         63       -8
 7:       dt     1 2013-07-11            6         34        5
 8:    henry     1 2013-07-04            4         NA       NA
 9:    sarah     2 2013-08-09            5         NA       NA
10:    sarah     3 2013-07-21            8        -19        3
11:    sarah     4 2013-06-23            9        -28        1
12:    sarah     5 2013-06-02            1        -21       -8
13:    sarah     1 2013-08-20            8         79        7
```

Comment: You might want to add a line like `df <- data.table(df)` since the OP doesn't start with one.

Comment: you need to remove the internal.selfref part from `dput` for it to be useful for other people